# Magento 1.8 some orders are giving white screen

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, orders, adminhtml, ce-1.8.0.0, migration

After migrating from 1.7 to 1.8, i get a white screen with some orders. 
If i check for page source, at the very end i have

> "**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function getProductOptions() on
>   a non-object in
>
> **/chroot/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View/Items/Renderer.php**
>   on line **64**"

I have enabled logs and in system.log i have:

```
2014-02-09T12:00:58+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <config/>
2014-02-09T12:00:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <config/>
2014-02-09T12:00:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <config/>
2014-02-09T12:01:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <?xml version="1.0"?><jstranslator></jstranslator>
2014-02-09T12:01:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <?xml version="1.0"?><config></config>
2014-02-09T12:01:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <config/>
2014-02-09T12:01:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <config/>
2014-02-09T12:01:09+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <config/>
```

I have tried to disable each module i use, but error still pops up.

I would apreciate some help.

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find the problem?